# Repair heavily damaged filesystem

Tags: login, filesystem

I am currently stuck on a login loop in ubuntu, and the other answer 
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
does not help. After a bit more troubleshooting I think the filesystem is damaged because i cannot cd into my own home folder, giving an error of "/home/gink is not a directory". FSCK does not help, any ideas?

This is on my VM which started happening when my host OS BSOD while I was using my vm.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a non-ubuntu host OS.  I'd create another ubuntu vm, and attach this "corrupt" disk over to that new VM and see if you can poke around on it and get your data off.

Comment: Sadly, the data is in the home directory which is now recognized as a file.

Comment: Have you tried [testDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)?

Comment: I don't suppose you have a backup or snapshot of the vm?

Comment: Is this Oracle Virtualbox? If so, bring up the app, close the VM, and DON'T save the current state. Then select the Ubuntu VM in the left pane, go to the **Machine** menu and select **Discard Saved State**. Restart the VM and see if you can log in normally.